# (3^n + 2^n) % 10 for large n

Tags: c++

So I have a number N that has maximum 9 digits and I have to get the last digit of 3^n + 2^n. Is there a rule for this kind of problem? The code I have so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("input.in");
ofstream fout("input.out");

int main(){
int n;
fin>>n;

fout<<fmod(pow(3,n)+pow(2,n),10);
}
```

However, If I use this and n is greater than 1000 it displays nan.

My question is: Is there a rule to such a problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, we know that `(3^n + 2^n) % 10` = `((3^n % 10) + (2^n % 10)) % 10`, so we can use [Modular Exponentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) to quickly solve this.

The basic premise is that `3^n % 10 = (3 * (3^(n-1) % 10)) % 10`

Comment: @ChorMay Glad to help!

Answer (score 7):

Well, the easiest answer is the following:

```
3^0 === 1;
3^1 === 3;
3^2 === 9;
3^3 === 7;
3^4 === 1;
3^5 === 3;
```

So, 3^n has last digit of 3, 9, 7 or 1, based on N. So, 
N%4 == 0 => last digit of 3^n is 1, == 1 =>3, == 2 => 9, == 3 => 7.

You can write out the same for 2^n:

1, **2, 4, 8, 6**, 2, ...

This cycle can be repeated all the time, ruling out the primary rule: last digit for 2^n is:

```
N == 0 => 1
N > 0 => 
    (N - 1) % 4 == 0 => 2
    (N - 1) % 4 == 1 => 4
    (N - 1) % 4 == 2 => 8
    (N - 1) % 4 == 3 => 6
```

After you calculated the last digit for both 3^n and 2^n, just add them together.

Comment: That's a great way of thinking, thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it mathematically. Let's look at the sequence u<sub>n</sub> = 3^n % 10: u<sub>0</sub> = 1, and then 3, 9, 7, and 1 again. It gives immediately:

u<sub>4k</sub> = 1, u<sub>4k+1</sub> = 3, u<sub>4k+2</sub> = 9, u<sub>4k+3</sub> = 7

Now look at v<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup> % 10: v<sub>0</sub>= 1 and then 2,4,8,6, and 2 again. It gives that for k > 0:

v<sub>4k</sub> = 6, v<sub>4k+1</sub> = 2, v<sub>4k+2</sub> = 4, v<sub>4k+3</sub> = 8

You immediately have the result: for N > 1 just look at N' = N%4, and the results are respectively 7, 5, 3, 5

In C++, it will give:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("input.in");
ofstream fout("input.out");

int main(){

    int n;
    fin>>n;

    int result[] = { 7,5,3,5};
    fout<<(n == 0) ? 2 : result[n%4];
    return 0;
}
```